# Django Application Dockerisation in Production

Tags: python-3.x, docker, containers, devops, infrastructure

We are shifting our existing Django Application which was deployed in EC2 with gunicorn and nginx. Wanted to know that what are the best practices for deploying Django in Docker? Can we directly run manage.py in production or should we use nginx and gunicorn inside docker? Since we have multiple django application, should we include gunicorn and nginx in every container or make some individual arrangements?